# Why subset doesn't mind missing subset argument for dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Normally I wonder where mysterious errors come from but now my question is where a mysterious lack of error comes from.

Let

```
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3)
frame <- as.data.frame(numbers)
```

If I type

```
subset(numbers, )
```

(so I want to take some subset but forget to specify the subset-argument of the subset function) then R reminds me (as it should):

> Error in subset.default(numbers, ) :
>   argument "subset" is missing, with no default

However when I type

```
subset(frame,)
```

(so the same thing with a `data.frame` instead of a vector), it doesn't give an error but instead just returns the (full) dataframe.

What is going on here? Why don't I get my well deserved error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr**: The `subset` function calls different functions (has different methods) depending on the type of object it is fed. In the example above, `subset(numbers, )` uses `subset.default` while `subset(frame, )` uses `subset.data.frame`.

---

R has a couple of object-oriented systems built-in. The simplest and most common is called S3. This OO programming style implements what Wickham calls a "generic-function OO." Under this style of OO, an object called a generic function looks at the class of an object and then applies the proper method to the object. If no direct method exists, then there is always a default method available.

To get a better idea of how S3 works and the other OO systems work, you might check out the relevant portion of the [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) site. The procedure of finding the proper method for an object is referred to as method dispatch. You can read more about this in the help file `?UseMethod`.

As noted in the Details section of `?subset`, the `subset` function "is a generic function." This means that `subset` examines the class of the object in the first argument and then uses method dispatch to apply the appropriate method to the object.

The methods of a generic function are encoded as

> < generic function name >.< class name >

and can be found using `methods(<generic function name>)`. For `subset`, we get

```
methods(subset)
[1] subset.data.frame subset.default    subset.matrix    
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

which indicates that if the object has a data.frame class, then `subset` calls the `subset.data.frame` the method (function). It is defined as below:

```
subset.data.frame
function (x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...) 
{
    r <- if (missing(subset)) 
        rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x))
    else {
        e <- substitute(subset)
        r <- eval(e, x, parent.frame())
        if (!is.logical(r)) 
            stop("'subset' must be logical")
        r & !is.na(r)
    }
    vars <- if (missing(select)) 
        TRUE
    else {
        nl <- as.list(seq_along(x))
        names(nl) <- names(x)
        eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame())
    }
    x[r, vars, drop = drop]
}
```

Note that if the subset argument is missing, the first lines

```
    r <- if (missing(subset)) 
        rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x))
```

produce a vector of TRUES of the same length as the data.frame, and the last line

```
    x[r, vars, drop = drop]
```

feeds this vector into the row argument which means that if you did not include a subset argument, then the `subset` function will return all of the rows of the data.frame.

As we can see from the output of the `methods` call, `subset` does not have methods for atomic vectors. This means, as your error

> Error in subset.default(numbers, )

that when you apply `subset` to a vector, R calls the `subset.default` method which is defined as

```
subset.default
function (x, subset, ...) 
{
    if (!is.logical(subset)) 
        stop("'subset' must be logical")
    x[subset & !is.na(subset)]
}
```

The `subset.default` function throws an error with `stop` when the subset argument is missing.