# Why `args()` in `R` don't always print agruments of method?

Tags: r

Function of `args()` is to :

> Displays the argument names and corresponding default values of a
>   function or primitive

but `args(subset)` for example print only :

```
> args(subset)
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

why does it sometimes works and sometimes don't ?

Comment: Perhaps because it's a generic? Try `args(subset.data.frame)`, for example

Comment: Those *are* the arguments for `subset`. You can see this by typing `subset` into the console and hitting enter.

Comment: Here is a closely [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348562/why-subset-doesnt-mind-missing-subset-argument-for-dataframes/39348718#39348718).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `args()` is an S3 generic method

```
subset
#function (x, ...) 
#UseMethod("subset")
#<bytecode: 0x1ee3ee0>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

So when you run `args(subset)` you are getting the arguments of the function - just not the function you would like.

A S3 generic method looks at the class of the object `x` and dispatches to another function. To see the available function use `methods()`.

```
R> methods(subset)
[1] subset.data.frame subset.default    subset.matrix    
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```