# How can I use check.names = false but still use the operator $

Tags: r, import

I have column names that contain brackets and spaces. I can import them using `check.names = False`.

However, after importing the subset function does not work anymore. I have tried the following codes

```
test <- subset (df$"model code" == graph)
test <- subset (df, "model code" == graph)
test <- subset (df$'model code' == graph)
```

This is the output error

> Error in subset.default(df$`model mode` == "graph") : 
>     argument "subset" is missing, with no default

How can I use check.names is false but still use the operator $

This worked but a new error has occurred downstream using the following code below **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'G' not found** any ideas on how to fix this?

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes_string("Sample",i)) + 
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
    geom_beeswarm(aes(color = Sample), size=2)
```

Comment: Use ```test <- subset (df$`model code` == graph)```

Comment: yes, tried it but it does not work for some reason

Comment: Please copy and paste the ouput from `dupt(df)` here by editing your question.

Comment: Does the top answer to this question explain your error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348562/why-subset-doesnt-mind-missing-subset-argument-for-dataframes  (per the link: "The subset function calls different functions (has different methods) depending on the type of object it is fed. In the example above, subset(numbers, ) uses subset.default while subset(frame, ) uses subset.data.frame" so if you post the output of `dput(df)` as requested by @Bappa_Das we should be able to solve your problem)

Comment: You need to specify `df` as first argument: `test <- subset(df, df$`model code` == graph)`

Comment: @M.Papenberg You should not use `df$` in `subset`'s second parameter. `subset` uses non-standard evaluation for convenience. If you type that much, better use `[` with standard evaluation (it's often better practice anyway).

Comment: @Roland: It does work though ;) And I wasn't sure if the `subset` parameter can handle a column name such as ` model code` without testing. (Apparently it does, as shown in the now accepted solution).

Comment: @M.Papenberg There are cases where it doesn't work correctly. NSE can be dangerous.

Comment: A new issue occurred. Please see the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use back-ticks like so, and probably you need quotes around your factor level.

```
subset(dat, `model code` == "graph")
#   model code          x
# 5      graph  1.8951935
# 7      graph -0.2572694
```

If you want `$`, better do subsetting using brackets:

```
dat[dat$"model code" == "graph", ]
#   model code          x
# 5      graph  1.8951935
# 7      graph -0.2572694
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
 filter(`model code` == 'graph')
```

Make sure to put both backticks.